# NgBootstrap Accordion component

Tags: ng-bootstrap

How to have multiple panels > multiple accordions / multiple panels > single accordion closed with a button click?

tried using "closeOthers" mentioned in the api but that does not work

Comment: I dont understant your question. Can you specify more your desired behavior?

Comment: Sorry Juan, i will try to present it in a simpler way

lets say there is an accordion with 5 panels and a button saying collapse all. if i have multiple panels opened then i should be able to collapse all the panels by clicking collapse all

similarly if i have multiple accordions with 2 panels each is there a way to expand all the panels at once after i click a button which says expand all?

Answer (score 1):

In your html file

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" (panelChange)="beforeChange($event)">
  <ngb-panel title="Title 1" id="id1">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Panel 1
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel title="Title 2" id="id2">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Panel 2
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel title="Title 3" id="id3">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Panel 3
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>

<button (click)="closeAll(acc)">Close all</button>
```

In your ts file

```
  panels = [
    { id: 'id1', state: true },
    { id: 'id2', state: true },
    { id: 'id3', state: true }
  ];

  public beforeChange($event: NgbPanelChangeEvent) {
    for (let panel of this.panels) 
      if (panel.id === $event.panelId)
        panel.state = !panel.state;
  }

  closeAll(acc) {
    for (let panel of this.panels) 
      if (!panel.state)
        acc.toggle(panel.id);
  }
```

You mantain an array of objects with the panels id and state. When you interact with one of the panels you use `beforeChange()` to change the state of the panel.
When you click on the button Close all you `toggle()` only the panels with the open state.

Comment: Hi Juan,

a slight difference in the problem statement

lets say i have multiple accordions each having one panel. 

how would the closeAll function work in this case?

Comment: You should now mantain an array of accordions. Every accordion in the array is an object with an accordion id and an array of panels. Each panel is an object with id and state. In the closeAll() function you have to pass as arguments all of the accordion variable templates. With this approach you have one more nested loop in your functions, to search inside the accordions array.